# Dynamic xpaths in Appium

Tags: xpath, appium

Trying to Automatize Testing of an Android app. However, the elements don't have any IDs attached to them, only `xpaths`. These `xpaths` are dynamic and can change depending on the screen size and the elements location on the screen.

I have tried to use contains() function, but in some cases there is no common nominator. This also doesn't seem to be the most reliable way.

Example:

> /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[4]

changes to

> /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]

when scrolling down on the screen.

What would be the best and most reliable solution? The same test script should run on multiple devices with varying screen sizes.

Is it even recommended to use xpaths in Appium or should I go to the developers and ask for unique IDs for each element?

Comment: Using Xpath is not recommended in Appium, Better you go for Unique ID, if its available!!
You can try Appium Desktop, before approaching to developer to get the ID.

Answer (score 0):

using xpath is not recommended. You must ask your developer to put unique id for each element that you want to interact with.

The recommended way is to use

- Find element by **ID**
- Find element by **Accessibility ID**

You can ask developer to put unique **cont-desc** in the element if you want to use **findElementByAccessibilityId()**.

```
MobileElemet element = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("your cont-desc id")
```

or you can ask developer to put unique **id** in the the element if you want to use **findElementById()**.

```
MobileElemet element = driver.findElementById("element's id")
```

> you can verify if the app element contains **id** or **cont-desc** by using **Appium Desktop Inspector** or **uiautomatorviewer**